# Matrix multiplication computational complexity based on radix 2

Tags: fft, matrix, complex, linear-algebra

I am wondering, can we use Radix 2 based computational-complexity calculation for any matrix multiplication whose size is $N$ x $N$ ?? where $N$ = $2^K$ and $K > 1$ is an integer ?? Or it can only used for FFT matrix?

and if I have a unitary complex matrix whose size $2$x$2$ multiplied with a real vector $2$x$1$; in that case the complexity is 6, can I use the radix-2 to recalculate that complexity with less required operations?

Comment: When researching Radix-2, you'll likely have figured out that it's the symmetry of the DFT matrix that makes it possible; so, maybe you want to elaborate on where your doubts come from?

Comment: by the way, how do you arrive at complexity 6? I can't find the same result.

Comment: and: is this *really* about 2×2 matrices applied to 2-length vectors? Because you'll find that the naive DFT of size 2 is trivial, and doesn't profit from radix-2 at all, so it's not quite sure whether you're on the right track! Maybe give some context (it's always a good idea). Explain why you came to the conclusion an unitary matrix calculation would be doable using radix-2 (I think there's a lot of good thought here; your question doesn't sound like a wild guess! I just don't understand where this is coming from); for which $N$ do you really care? Give us a rough idea of the size of the

Comment: real-world problem your tackling! Unitary matrices have a lot of nice properties, maybe there's some other approach to solving the problem that can actually be more efficient.

Comment: I got, Radix-2 can only be used with symmetry matrices,

Comment: ah, symmetry is not sufficient: Radix-2 works because of the Vandermonde matrix structure of the DFT. It doesn't work for just any Hermitian symmetric matrix; the "symmetry" goes much deeper. My first comment wasn't very precise. Still hoping for your edit to your question, where you give context about your problem and explain how you came up with the idea! (I'm a bit very eagerly waiting, because chances are the question might be closed without)